# Asynchronous function call from synchronous function (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, puppeteer

I am having trouble with getting access to a response from my asynchronous function. I understand this is a common issue, but I cannot find another question that pertains to my issue.

My Synchronous Function:

```
const output = getSeasons.getSeasons('*URL*', (data)=>{
        return data
    })
  console.log(data)
```

My Asynchronous Function:

```
const getSeasons = async (url, callback) => {

     seasonTitle = *ASYNCHRONOUS CALL THAT RETURNS AN ARRAY*

        await seasonTitle
        callback(seasonTitle) 
}
```

My issue is that I want to be able to continue in my synchronous function utilizing "output" in future lines. The only solution I can think of is:

```
const output = getSeasons.getSeasons('*URL*', (data)=>{
            return data
        }).then(()=>{  console.log(data)  }
```

My issue with this option is that all of my future code for this function will have to be written inside the ".then" function. I would much prefer to wait for a response before continuing on in my synchronous function without putting everything in ".then". Mainly because I will have multiple functions calling asynchronous functions and that will result in multiple nested ".then" functions.

EDIT:

Here is the actual code, the asynchronous call is scraping for elements with a class of seasons and then I am trying to return the array:

```
const output = getSeasons.getSeasons('https://www.rocketleagueesports.com/schedule/', (data)=>{
        console.log(data)
    })

    console.log(output)


const getSeasons = async (url, callback) => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true })
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto(url)
    await page.waitForSelector('.match') //Waits for elements with class "match" to load before executing further


        const seasonTitle = page.evaluate(() => {
            const seasonTitleArray = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.sub-header .scoreboard-container .container-lg .show-on-md .select-options-container .seasons li'))
            return seasonTitleArray.map(li => li.textContent)
        })

        await seasonTitle 
        callback(seasonTitle)

}
```

Comment: For us to help you in the most useful way, you need to show your ACTUAL code with the actual asynchronous operations.  Then, we can advise whether you should use existing native promise interfaces, promisify non-promise callback interfaces, return promises directly, use `await`, etc...  With this pseudo code, all we could really do is launch into a tutorial on how this all works which could easily be a couple chapters in a book.

Comment: But, the first thing you must understand is that you cannot obtain an asynchronous result in a synchronous fashion.  That means you can never directly return an asynchronous result from a synchronous function either.   Once any part of your result is asynchronous, the entire result must be communicated back to the caller using an asynchronous mechanism such as promise, callback or event.

Comment: ***I would much prefer to wait for a response before continuing on in my synchronous function without putting everything in ".then".*** Welcome to asynchronous programming in Javasacript.  This is how things work.  You can learn how to use `await` with promises and improve the "look" of your code, but it will still be asynchronous and the result to any caller will still be asynchronous.

Comment: I added an edit to the question. As you can tell, I'm new to nodejs and asynchronous functions. Is what I'm asking simply not possible? Will I not be able to get the array returned and store it in "output"?

Comment: Nope.  `getSeasons()` returns a promise, not a regular value.  You have to use `await` or `.then()` on `getSeasons()` to get it's value.  That's how `async` functions work in Javascript.  Plus, you don't even have a return value from `getSeasons()` so that promise will resolve to `undefined` anyway.

Comment: I went ahead and made my main function an async function and everything is going much smoother. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the **await** as you have done in **getSeasons**

```
const getSeasons = async funciton(url) {
   return await *ASYNCHRONOUS CALL THAT RETURNS AN ARRAY*
}

(async () => {
  const output = await getSeasons.getSeasons('*URL*')
  console.log(output)
})()
```

[async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await)

Comment: The second await is not in an async function

Comment: @charlietfl fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to write code in `then` block, then use `async/await`

```
async someFunction() {
    const output = await getSeasons.getSeasons(...)
}
```

Besides that, your `getSessions` need some improvements. Why do you need both callback and `async` which return a Promise?

Try to refactor something like this:

```
const getSeasons = async function(url) {
   return *ASYNCHRONOUS CALL THAT RETURNS AN ARRAY*
}
```

Comment: Oh okay, this makes a lot of sense. So since I wont be able to get my result back into the synchronous function I would either have to use ".then" or just make my synchronous function asynchronous and manage everything with await